# QAxObject Excel sheet -- set default font for entire Excel sheet

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qaxobject

I am able to set the size & font of a single cell.

```
QAxObject *range = excelSheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", row, col);
range = range->querySubObject("Font");
range->setProperty("Size", 10);
range->setProperty("Name", "Arial");
```

How can i change the FONT `default` size & type of full excel sheet `?`

Answer (score 1):

See http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/10304/52610.aspx, you have to select all the cells in the sheet (as a range), and then select the font for them. Try to adapt the following VB code:

```
xlsRange := xlsWorksheet.Cells;
xlsRange.Font.Name := 'Zapf Dingbats';
```

Comment: What is the right call to get all excel cells in QT.. i am not able to find much about this in QAobject help document. Please suggest ..?

Comment: is there some function for this ... or do i have to put for() loop for this... ?

Comment: You'll have to figure this out by yourself, I'm not familiar with the `QAxObject` class and how it works.